Grapevine SendResponseAsync length
I have simple sample in Winforms.net (framework 4.8)  to return response though await context.Response.SendResponseAsync(json);
If json is larger then 2048 characters Grapevine server crash and response is Pending on client.
Where can I extend size of response, I would like to send larger files?

I have no idea what to change.

Can you include the version of Grapevine you are using?

Your code is using ContentType.Json instead of ContentType.JSON, so I'll assume this is Grapevine 5.x

I have reproduced your code with both Grapevine 4 and Grapevine 5 using a file with over 40,000 characters and I am unable to reproduce this issue.
